# Rebuild/Verify Ruby on Rails Bcrypt password hash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I have to rebuild a project from Ruby on Rails to Node.js.
Bcrypt was used to hash passwords in the Ruby project and I'm trying to rebuild the same hash so I can copy the hashed password and users can login with the same credentials on the node version.

This hash `$2a$11$j2IA8cPRFFC4YOXTl5kb9eF02fwNdLyFAPOvflQ3h/QdX8mE1SNK2` is used for the password `Test1234`. I've checked the Ruby on Rails code and I saw the following function to hash a password

**General info**

```
COST = 11
SALT = 1234567890
```

**Create hash**

```
def password_hash(password)
  pwd = "#{password}#{SALT}"
  ::BCrypt::Password.create(pwd, cost: COST)
end
```

**Does passwords match?**

```
def password_match?(password = nil)
  password ||= @params[:password]
  encrypted_password = get_encrypted_password
  return false if !encrypted_password || encrypted_password.size < 8

  pwd = "#{password}#{SALT}"
  BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password) == pwd
end

def get_encrypted_password
  return unless @account

  @account.encrypted_password
end
```

As far as I know something about Ruby this means that in the `password_match` function, pwd would be `Test12341234567890` and `BCrypt::Password.new($2a$11$j2IA8cPRFFC4YOXTl5kb9eF02fwNdLyFAPOvflQ3h/QdX8mE1SNK2)` checks if `Test12341234567890 (pwd)` matches the hash.

When I use an online Bcrypt verifier like https://bcrypt.online/ and enter the hash together with the pwd value I don't get a match.

I also tried to use the `bcrypt.compare` method in the Javascript package but this didn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried your password_hash function with "Test1234" and the salt you provided. Got `$2a$11$bhdYASCaEPv/0HXv3OFtIupv8CgHFoEWkMonShKnNN1fkmRIg.07S` as a result, ran it through the online verifier you linked and got "The supplied hash matches with supplied plain text".

Comment: `BCrypt::Password.new(password_hash("Test1234")) == "Test12341234567890"` Also works out fine and returns true.

Comment: Also tried Node.js with bcryptjs and did `bcrypt.compareSync('Test12341234567890', "$2a$11$bhdYASCaEPv/0HXv3OFtIupv8CgHFoEWkMonShKnNN1fkmRIg.07S")`. Also works out fine and returns true.

Comment: @Swiffy I tried the same steps before and they all worked but what I need is a match for the encrypted passwords I currently have in the database.

`bcrypt.compareSync('Test1234123456789', "$2a$11$j2IA8cPRFFC4YOXTl5kb9eF02fwNdLyFAPOvflQ3h/QdX8mE1SNK2")`. I can't recreate a hash since we are not longer working with Ruby. I just need a way to check if an earlier created hash in Ruby is valid for the provided password with node.js

Comment: My example does exactly that. I generated that `$2a$11$bhd......Ig.07S` hash with your Ruby function, from the word "Test1234" + salt "1234567890". On the Node.js side I called `compareSync` with the hash from the Ruby function.

Comment: @Swiffy Yes that's a new hash you created with the same methods. But for some reason the already created hash `$2a$11$j2IA8cPRFFC4YOXTl5kb9eF02fwNdLyFAPOvflQ3h/QdX8mE1SNK2` for password Test1234 that is currently stored in the database doesn't pass the online verification test and the `compareSync` test in node.js

Comment: That should give you the idea that the problem is not with the Ruby's hash creation function, nor is it with the Node's hash testing function, but somewhere else (which is technically outside the scope of this question). Maybe your database doesn't store the full hash for some reason, or stores it in a wrong way. Maybe something somewhere strips or escapes some characters in the hash, leaving you with incomplete one. Maybe some of the aforementioned happens to the salt. Maybe the hash in the database was generated by a different or older hash function. Maybe the salt has changed.

Comment: @Swiffy Thanks for the comment! With your comment I found out that they used a different salt than the one inside the .env file. It was stored in the config variables of Heroku. Everything is working now!

Comment: Let me post this whole shenanigans as an answer then 

Comment: What is "SALT"? Why are you passing `"#{password}#{SALT}"` to BCrypt? BCrypt generates a unique per-password salt, you don't have to manually append one, and if you're using the same global constant for each password, that's not a salt, it's a [cryptographic pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)), the use of which is discouraged.

Comment: @user229044 It's unclear why they did that. I haven't created the Ruby on Rails project. I'm just looking for a why to verify the current hashes in another code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we did an oopsie and solved this issue in the comments. Here is a recap of it all as an answer.

Me:

> I tried your password_hash function with "Test1234" and the salt you
> provided. Got
> $2a$11$bhdYASCaEPv/0HXv3OFtIupv8CgHFoEWkMonShKnNN1fkmRIg.07S as a
> result, ran it through the online verifier you linked and got "The
> supplied hash matches with supplied plain text".
>
> BCrypt::Password.new(password_hash("Test1234")) ==
> "Test12341234567890" Also works out fine and returns true.
>
> Also tried Node.js with bcryptjs and did
> bcrypt.compareSync('Test12341234567890',
> "$2a$11$bhdYASCaEPv/0HXv3OFtIupv8CgHFoEWkMonShKnNN1fkmRIg.07S"). Also
> works out fine and returns true.

Thore:

> Yes that's a new hash you created with the same methods. But for some
> reason the already created hash
> $2a$11$j2IA8cPRFFC4YOXTl5kb9eF02fwNdLyFAPOvflQ3h/QdX8mE1SNK2 for
> password Test1234 that is currently stored in the database doesn't
> pass the online verification test and the compareSync test in node.js

Me:

> That should give you the idea that the problem is not with the Ruby's
> hash creation function, nor is it with the Node's hash testing
> function, but somewhere else (which is technically outside the scope
> of this question). Maybe your database doesn't store the full hash for
> some reason, or stores it in a wrong way. Maybe something somewhere
> strips or escapes some characters in the hash, leaving you with
> incomplete one. Maybe some of the aforementioned happens to the salt.
> Maybe the hash in the database was generated by a different or older
> hash function. Maybe the salt has changed.

Thore:

> Thanks for the comment! With your comment I found out that they used a
> different salt than the one inside the .env file. It was stored in the
> config variables of Heroku. Everything is working now!